# Install both Debug and Release configurations of static library in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries, static-linking, linkage

I switched to [catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2) 3.0, which is now represented as static library and faced the problem of its build type (configuration). To install catch2 it should be built either with Release or Debug config, so you'll have the corresponding .lib file in your install path. But! I can link it against my project only if it (project) has the same config. So if I want to switch the config of my project, I have to reinstall catch2 with appropriate config.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio you may not want to build the INSTALL target at all. I don't. Instead I point CMake to the build folder when I need to use a library in some other project.

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you for help! Doesn't that mean hardcoding the library path?

Comment: No when you configure your application in CMake-gui instead of pointing to the INSTALL location you point to the root folder of build tree where you built the third party library.

Comment: Why not integrate catch2 using FetchContent() thus it will be built with the same config...

Answer (score 0):

Two possible options off the top of my head:

---

Option 1. install `catch2` to 2 seperate dirs:

- Build `Release` and `Debug` of `catch2`
- Install to two different locations (`/path/to/rel` & `/path/to/debug`)
- In your project, for `Release` and `Debug` build tree, set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to one of those, respectively.

This method is clear and simple, and guaranteed to work.

NOTE: you do not have to hard code library path in your project, since the path is passed to cmake as command line/GUI argument.

---

Option 2. Use `CMAKE_<CONFIG>_POSTFIX` to distinguish different builds

This one I'm not quite sure of, but I just wanna point out that cmake does provide this feature. Here's the [doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CONFIG_POSTFIX.html).

For example, if you set `CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX` as `-debug`, then the `Debug` library file will be renamed from `foo` to `foo-debug`, while `Release` library will still be `foo`. Then they can live in the same folder.

Just so you know, I've never tried this feature myself. And I believe it kinda depends on the quality of `catch2`'s cmake Config file (if it has one). So YMMV if you wanna try out this option.